# jQuery serializeArray() pairs

Tags: jquery

I have the following JSON:

```
[
   {"name":"recid","value":"6028"},
   {"name":"notes","value":""},
   {"name":"recid","value":"6029"},
   {"name":"notes","value":""},
   {"name":"recid","value":"6030"},
   {"name":"notes","value":""},
   {"name":"recid","value":"6031"},
   {"name":"notes","value":""}
]
```

I am generating it by doing this?

```
      // Serialize form data
      var data = table.$('input,select,textarea').serializeArray();

      // Include extra data if necessary
      //data.push({'name': 'orderid', 'value': <%=orderid%>});

      alert (JSON.stringify(data));
```

How do I get the data to look like this:

```
[
   {"recid":6028,"notes":null},
   {"recid":6029,"notes":null}
]
```

Comment: Your desired JSON is invalid.

Comment: Hi, I copied and pasted the JSON above to https://jsonlint.com/ and it says it is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reduce loop can help populate the data like you want. With comments:

```
let data = incoming.reduce((b, a, i) => { // b is the accumlating array, a is the iteration, i is index
  let prev = i > 0 ? b.length - 1 : 0 // get the prev array index
  if (i > 0 && i % 2) b[prev][a.name] = a.value; // every other time add to the previous array object
  else b.push({ [a.name]: a.value }); // else start a new one
  return b
}, [])
```

```js
let incoming = [{"name":"recid","value":"6028"},{"name":"notes","value":"test notes"},{"name":"recid","value":"6029"},{"name":"notes","value":"test notes2"},{"name":"recid","value":"6030"},{"name":"notes","value":"test notes3"},{"name":"recid","value":"6031"},{"name":"notes","value":"test notes4"}]

let data = incoming.reduce((b, a, i) => {
  let prev = i > 0 ? b.length - 1 : 0
  if (i > 0 && i % 2) b[prev][a.name] = a.value;
  else b.push({
    [a.name]: a.value
  });
  return b
}, [])

console.log(data)
```